# bootStrap menu added items cannot reach asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Depending on what is the level of the client connecting to my web app, i have to show different menu items, that is why i just add them with this code :

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Level"]) >= 2)
        {
            MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem("MenuItem2", "SchoolView.aspx");
            mi2.ToolTip = "tool tip";
            mi2.Selectable = true;
            bootMenu.Items[0].ChildItems.Add(mi2);
        }
```

My menu header contain a click event. For items that are already in the menu, no problem, but those i add afterward dosen't seem to heritate of the click event. Here's my menu, in case it can help.

```
    <asp:Menu ID="bootMenu" 
    runat="server" 
    Orientation="Vertical" 
    StaticDisplayLevels="1"
    StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
    OnMenuItemClick="BootMenu_MenuItemClick" 
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10" 
    EnableViewState="false"
    CssClass="nav navbar-fix-top" 
    DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu" 
    IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
    SkipLinkText=""
    RenderingMode="List">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : ok i got it.

Make the menu redirect to the "welcome" page and this one is redirecting me correctly, seems like using the master page for something else then design is a bad idea.

---

EDIT : NO ! that thing dosen't work when on an IIS server.

All what is bellow is very random and not reacting properly.

---

Well... i just found a very bad way but it works :

```
MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("Accueil", "Default.aspx", null, "~\\?Menu=Default.aspx");
```

By making this menu item redirect to my Master Page with a string variable in the header, i can now use my master page to request and redirect :

```
    if (Request["Menu"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request["Menu"]);
        }
```

now it's my master page that redirect the user, not the menu itsef...